# pyserial when it is the end of the line stop the while loop

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('COM12', 9600, timeout = .1)
arduino_data = [] # declare a list

while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        arduino_data.append(data) # Append a data to your declared list
        print arduino_data
```

I wonder when there is no more new line from Arduino side, how can i jump out the while loop?

```
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        arduino_data.append(data) # Append a data to your declared list
        print arduino_data
        break
```

It only works for 1 line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing serial value after the loop is done from the Arduino side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942673/storing-serial-value-after-the-loop-is-done-from-the-arduino-side)

Comment: You have an extremely short timeout.  Are you sure this is the appropriate value?  Will the target be producing at least 10 lines per second?  I think @CaveMike has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for it to timeout without any data, then you know it is done.

For example:

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('COM12', 9600, timeout = .1)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        arduino_data.append(data) # Append a data to your declared list
        print(arduino_data)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Clearly I already tried that. It doesn't work at all. First iteration directly went to break, did not even wait for read.

Comment: Your code was missing the else before the break. If you already tried it with the else, then it means that the first read completes before data is ready. For debugging, try it with a bigger timeout. Right now, you have it at 100 ms. Try 1 second or 5 seconds. Depending on what device you are talking to and how your trigger it to send data, it might need more time to send data.

Comment: oh mike you are so brilliant! So now my concern is after the break, the program will stop, how do I restart it?

Comment: Write your code in a function and call it whenever necessary. Either a restart or a simple call.

Comment: So do you mind put some example code in the solution so I can understand better. Is there a build in restart?